# consulta nodejs y mongodb devuelve un arreglo vacio

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo un problema, el codigo no genera error, pero la consulta a la base de datos mongoDB con mongoose me devuelve un arreglo vacio y me genera la duda porque tengo en el mismo programa una porcion de codigo que si funciona pero con otro documento de la base

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const app = express();

const rescateSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: String,
    fecha: Date,
    encargado: String,
    comentarios: String,
    status: String,
    resultado: String
});


const rescateModel = mongoose.model('rescate', rescateSchema);

const mostrar = async () => {
    const rescate = await rescateModel.find()
    console.log(rescate)
}

//Mostramos la funcion que consulta los registros
mostrar()

module.exports = mongoose.model('rescate', rescateSchema);
```

Comment: No veo en qué momento realizas la conexión a la base de datos. Por otro lado, cuando uses `async / await` para trabajar con Promesas, has de hacerlo dentro de un bloque `try ... catch`. Por último, para que las `queries` de Mongoose devuelvan una Promesa, debes encadenar al final el método `exec()`, por ejemplo: `const rescate = await rescateModel.find().exec();`. Saludos

Comment: para que quede como solucion solo coloque lean() delante de find() y eso fue todo